# Бан ботов по юзерагенту через конфиг nginx

Tags: nginx

Хочу забанить ботов по юзерагенту через конфиг nginx. 
Банить всех чей юзерагент содержит: `crawler`, `spider` и `bot` (кроме `googlebot`)

Добавил в конфиг такие строки:

```
map $http_user_agent $bad_bot {
default 0;
~*(crawler|spider|(?<!google)bot)1;
}


   location / {

    if ($bad_bot = 1) {return 444;}

    }
```

Краулеров и спайдеров банит отлично, а вот bot'ов нет , видимо регулярка не срабатывает (хотя если проверяю в блокноте то работает).
Подскажите пожалуйста правильную регулярку для конфига, чтобы банило всех чей юзерагент содержит `bot` (кроме `googlebot`)

И подскажите заодно как, через этот же конфиг, забанить тех, чей юзерагент вообще пустой

Comment: Яндекс-бот плакает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно пытаться запихать всё в одну регулярку.

Я бы написал как-то так:

```
map $http_user_agent $bad_bot {
    default     0;
    ~*googlebot 0;
    ~*crawler   1;
    ~*spider    1;
    ~*bot       1;
}
```

ну или так, если у вас уже есть какая-то регулярка для ботов и нужно просто добавить исключение:

```
map $http_user_agent $bad_bot {
    default     0;
    ~*googlebot 0;
    ~*(crawler|spider|bot) 1;
}
```

Comment: У меня в этой регулярке еще огромный список ботов. Будет ли разница в производительности если оставить список в одной длинной регулярке, или лучше каждый бот в одну строку?

Comment: Ну, какая-то разница будет, но реально nginx это примерно последнее место где нужно искать узкие места. Писать можно как удобнее

Comment: в сравнении с гигантской регуляркой разница, скорее всего, будет в пользу map :)

Comment: `map`-то тоже эти же регулярки проверяет. В данном случае если чаще приходит гугл, то map будет сразу останавливаться и не будет проверять гигантскую регулярку. А если чаще приходят остальные, то добавится лишняя проверка на гуглбота. Но это всё такие копейки.

Comment: А можно ли как-то забанить парсильщиков с пустым юзерагентом ?

Comment: `~^$ 1;` — как-то так, наверное.

Comment: Думаю, лучче `''    1;` > А можно ли как-то забанить парсильщиков с пустым юзерагентом?

Comment: @norbornen точно, что-то я залип на регулярках =)
Для забана `fail2ban` и т.п.